# Shouldn't the average search time for a linked list be O(N/2)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, big-o

I keep seeing [the search time](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) for linked lists listed as O(N) but if you have 100 elements in a list aren't you on average only comparing against 50 of them before you've found a match?

So is O(N/2) being rounded to O(N) or am I just wrong in thinking it's N/2 on average for a linked list lookup?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no constants in big O notation.

Comment: That simplifies things greatly thanks :)

Comment: You also have to take into account the time required to find that there is no match. That requires comparing every item.

Comment: That's something you'd consider during design right? You wouldn't want to use a linked list for something where a search will frequently return back false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is, the order is really only talking about how the time increases as n increases.

So `O(N)` means that you have linear growth. If you double `N` then the time taken also doubles. `N/2` and `N` both have the same growth behaviour so in terms of Order they are identical.

Functions like `log(N)`, and `N^2` on the other hand have non-linear growth, `N^2` for example means that if you double `N` the time taken increases 4 times.

It is all about ratios. If something on average takes 1 minute for 1 item will it on average take 2 minutes or 4 minutes for 2 items? O(N) will be 2 minutes, O(N^2) will take 4 minutes. If the original took 1 second then O(N) will take 2 seconds, O(N^2) 4 seconds.

The algorithm that takes 1 minute and the algorithm that takes 1 second are both O(N)!

Comment: Thanks I do seem to remember somewhere in the back of my head about O notation being about upper bounds and growth rate. So it's important to distinguish when talking about run times vs. big O notation run times. Thanks!

Comment: To nitpick, f(N) in O(N) doesn't mean linear growth. It means it's eventually bounded by kN for some k. log(N) is O(N), and so is N + log(N), and so is N + cos(N), none of which have linear growth,

Comment: I can agree that N+cos(N) is since actually it is linear growth in the grand scheme of things (cos(N) always has a value from 0 to 1 so can be removed). N+log(N) on the other hand though surely is O(N+Log(N)), not O(N)?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers make the main points required for the answer, but there's a detail I'd like to add: If it's not explicitly stated, complexity statements typically discuss the worst case behaviour, rather than the average, simply because analysing the worst case behaviour is frequently a lot easier than the average behaviour. So if I say, without any additional qualifications, search in a linked list is O(N), then I'm admittedly being sloppy, but I would be talking about the worst case of search in a linked list taking a number of steps linear in N.

Answer (score 1):

The O means [something](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The average number of elements that need to be traversed, to find something in a linked list is N/2. N/2 = O(N).

Note that saying *search in linked list on average takes n/2 operations* is wrong as *operation* is not defined. I could argue that for each node you need to read it's value, compare it to what you are searching for and then read the pointer to next node, and thus that the algorithm performs 3N/2 operations on average. Using O notation allows us to avoid such insignificant details.

Comment: @advocate, if you want to convey the fact that, on average, only half of the list will be read, O notation will not help you.